# How to smooth cement trim/moulding on pillars?

Tags: trim, sanding, cement, finish

I'm getting my house painted and have about 20 decorative concrete pillars with cement trim/moulding (see pics below). The first contractor turned out to be a rookie and basically slathered paint on the trim making it looks ugly (pic 1st and 3rd). The second contractor hand sanded another pillar for 2 days (pic 2nd and 4th) and said that's about as good as it's gonna get. Is there any tool/method that I can use to speed up the sanding process and improve the end result? I'd really like a nice/smooth finish with clean/sharp design elements.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A sand blaster with nut media may work

Comment: Sand blaster will strip paint, but would it smoothen floral design without fading them?

Comment: https://walnutshellpowder.wordpress.com/tag/walnut-shell-sandblasting/.     Give this a read.

Answer (score 1):

They are plaster columns, they need to the stripped of the paint down to bare plaster and have a reputable plaster company repair them. There may be others out there that can do it, but you are taking the same chance that you already have. Plaster is a dying art, and you may be hard pressed to find one.

Comment: I confirmed, they are made of cement but do have a coat of paint on them. I was hoping someone can give me an idea of how to strip and smoothen them, so I can identify a contractor who recommends the same apprach.

Comment: I doubt they are made out of cement. I agree with @Jack , I think they are plaster (which could look like cement). I’d have a “plaster” contractor inspect it to confirm. (A few years ago in a nearby town, a car hit a column and took a chunk out of a “marble” column. When they inspected the column they discovered it was plaster made to look like marble.)